# TCPDF - SetAutoPageBreak Inicia el contenido de la siguiente página sobre el header y no debajo de el

Tags: html, laravel, tcpdf

Estoy trabajando con laravel y la librería TCPDF. Tengo poco usando TCPDF y me atore con las páginas que se generan de manera automática. Explico: Creo un formato de factura en html, por cada página se repetirá el header y el footer, si el contenido excede el tamaño de la pagina por lo siguiente se creara una siguiente pagina.

el problema es que el contenido del cuerpo de la factura se comienza a imprimir sobre el header y no debajo de el.

Les agradezco su ayuda. Saludos

Agrego unas fotos:

[image: esta es la primera hoja, como veran tambien me mueve la imagen qr]

[image: Esta seria la segunda hoja, donde se puede notar que el contenido lo imprime sobre el header y yo espero que lo imprima debajo de el, y siempre la ultima hoja, la imagen del QR queda bien]

Agrego mi codigo:

Esta es la primera clase que se llama para crear el pdf..

```
class PdfFunctions {
    public static function create($plantilla, $data) {
        if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'pdf/tmp.pdf'))
            unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'pdf/tmp.pdf');

        if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'pdf/tmp.png'))
            unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'pdf/tmp.png');

        $obj = new PdfFunctions();
        Session::put('config', $plantilla->config);

        $configuracion = $plantilla->config;
        $hotel = $plantilla->config->hotel;
        $correos = $plantilla->config->hotel->correos;
        $papel = $plantilla->config->papel;
        $idioma = $plantilla->idioma;
        $cadenaHeader = '';
        $cadenaBody = '';
        $cadenaFooter = '';

        $response = [];
        $html = '';
        $corte = '';
        $bandFooter = true;

        if ($configuracion->orientacion === 'P') {
            $alto = $papel->alto;
            $ancho = $papel->ancho;
        } else {
            $alto = $papel->ancho;
            $ancho = $papel->alto;
        }

        $estilos = '
            <style type="text/css">
                .header {

                }
                .body {

                }
                .footer {

                }
            </style>';

        $estilos = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $estilos);

        $cadena = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $configuracion->content_encabezado);
        if ($cadena !== '' && $cadena !== NULL)
            $cadenaHeader = $obj->getStringValues($cadena, $data);

        $cadena = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $configuracion->content_content);
        if ($cadena !== '' && $cadena !== NULL)
            $cadenaBody = $obj->getStringValues($cadena, $data);

        $cadena = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $configuracion->content_pie);
        if ($cadena !== '' && $cadena !== NULL)
            $cadenaFooter = $obj->getStringValues($cadena, $data);

        $header = $cadenaHeader;
        $body = $cadenaBody;
        $footer = $cadenaFooter;

        $html = $body;

        Session::put('header', $header);
        Session::put('pie', $footer);
        Session::put('SetY', ($configuracion->footer + $configuracion->bottom_margin));

        /*
         * Constructor Inicial
         */
        $pdf = new PDF($configuracion->orientacion, $configuracion->unidad_medida, [$alto,
                                                                                    $ancho], true, 'UTF-8', false);

        $pdf->SetMargins($configuracion->left_margin, $configuracion->top_margin, $configuracion->right_margin);

        $pdf->setPrintHeader(true);
        $pdf->setPrintFooter(true);

        $pdf->SetCreator('Yo Mero');
        $pdf->SetAuthor('Yo Merengues');
        $pdf->SetTitle('Yo Mero pdf by tcpdf');
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $configuracion->bottom_margin);

        $font = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(asset('fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf'), 'sans-serif', '', 32);
        $pdf->SetFont($font, '', $configuracion->font_size);
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(
            $w = 0,
            $h = ($alto - (Session::get('new_header') + Session::get('new_footer'))),
            $x = '',
            $y = Session::get('new_header'),
            $html,
            $border = 0,
            $ln = 1,
            $fill = 0,
            $reseth = false,
            $align = '',
            $autopadding = true
        );
        //  End Inicial

        /*
         * Liberación del Objeto Inicial
         */
        unset($pdf);
        //  End Liberación

        if ($configuracion->content_pie === '' || $configuracion->content_pie === NULL) {
            $corte = $configuracion->bottom_margin;
            $bandFooter = false;
        } else {
            $corte = Session::get('new_footer');
            $bandFooter = true;
        }

        /*
         * Construcción Final
         */
        $pdf = new PDF($configuracion->orientacion, $configuracion->unidad_medida, [$alto,
                                                                                    $ancho], true, 'UTF-8', false);

        $pdf->SetMargins($configuracion->left_margin, $configuracion->top_margin, $configuracion->right_margin);

        $pdf->setPrintHeader(true);
        $pdf->setPrintFooter($bandFooter);

        $pdf->SetCreator('SiHoteles');
        $pdf->SetAuthor('SiHoteles');
        $pdf->SetTitle('SiHoteles pdf con tcpdf');
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $corte);

        $font = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(asset('fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf'), 'sans-serif', '', 32);
        $pdf->SetFont($font, '', $configuracion->font_size);
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(
            $w = 0,
            $h = ($alto - (Session::get('new_header') + Session::get('new_footer'))),
            $x = '',
            $y = Session::get('new_header'),
            $html,
            $border = 0,
            $ln = 1,
            $fill = 0,
            $reseth = false,
            $align = '',
            $autopadding = true
        );
        //  End Final

        Session::forget('config');
        Session::forget('new_header');
        Session::forget('new_footer');
        Session::forget('header');
        Session::forget('pie');
        Session::forget('SetY');

        return $pdf->Output('tmp.pdf', 'E');
    }

    public
    function getStringValues($cadena, $data) {
        $htmlAux = preg_split("'<\?php(.*?)\?>'", $cadena);
        preg_match_all("'<\?php(.*?)\?>'", $cadena, $php);
        $php = $php['1'];

        $aux = 0;
        ob_start();
        foreach ($htmlAux as $key => $value) {
            echo $value;
            if (isset($php[$aux])) {
                eval($php[$aux]);
                $aux++;
            }
        }

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase del custom header and footer:

```
class PDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Header() {
        $font = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(asset('fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf'), 'sans-serif', '', 32);
        $this->SetFont($font, '', Session::get('config.font_size'));
        $this->writeHTMLCell(
            $w = 0,
            $h = Session::get('config.header'),
            $x = '',
            $y = Session::get('config.top_margin'),
            Session::get('header'),
            $border = 0,
            $ln = 1,
            $fill = 0,
            $reseth = true,
            $align = '',
            $autopadding = true
        );

        Session::put('new_header', ($this->getLastH() + Session::get('config.top_margin')));
    }

    public function Footer() {
        $this->SetY(Session::get('SetY'));
        $font = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(asset('fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf'), 'sans-serif', '', 32);
        $this->SetFont($font, '', Session::get('config.font_size'));
        $this->writeHTMLCell(
            $w = 0,
            $h = Session::get('config.footer'),
            $x = '',
            $y = '',
            Session::get('pie'),
            $border = 0,
            $ln = 1,
            $fill = 0,
            $reseth = true,
            $align = '',
            $autopadding = true
        );

        Session::put('new_footer', ($this->getLastH() + Session::get('config.bottom_margin')));
        Session::put('SetY', '-'.Session::get('new_footer'));

        $this->Cell(0, 0, 'Hoja '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya está resuelto el primer problema: "El contenido de las paginas añadidas se imprima sobre el header"... Lo que pasa que cuando defino la posición Y del header, este ya no respeta `$pdf->SetMargins($configuracion->left_margin, $configuracion->top_margin, $configuracion->right_margin);` por lo tanto, el contenido aún sigue las normas de este margen. Así que simplemente asigne el nuevo alto que tendrá el contenido: `$pdf->SetMargins($configuracion->left_margin, Session::get('new_header'), $configuracion->right_margin, true);`.

Comment: Ya solo queda el dilema del porque la imagen (código QR en png) me la está moviendo de lugar y volteando

Comment: Ya quedo resuelto el problema de las imágenes en el footer. Lo que se tuvo que hacer es encerrar el footer en el break de la página y después reajustarlo.

Comment: `$bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();` `$auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;` `$this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);` |aqui va el codigo del footer| `$this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);`